# Model passed to Controller become null when receive too much passing field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a model that combine default data when generate Razor pages and new input data. Both of them will be passing to Controller to handle. I have done it with multiple Razor pages, with a base model that contain common field but in this new Page, I have stumble upon this error which I don't know how to dealt with it. In the deepest floor of the Model, it would only accept one field. If I try to pass more than one, my entire model in Controller become a null value.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens.Count; i++)
{
//Value for Model
<input type="hidden" asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].CttvId" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].CttvThuocBangId" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].CauHinhBangId" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].TenDong" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].CongThucDong" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].DichCongThuc" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].listId" />
var dataTarget = "#collapse" + i.ToString();
var tempid = "collapse" + i.ToString();
var danhmuc = Model.layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens.ElementAt(i);
for (int x = 0; x < danhmuc.TenDongThuocCongTies.Count; x++)
{
<input type="hidden" asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[x].CauHinhBangId" />
//If I un-comment even one of the line below, the model become null.
//Each of them field is not special. I can comment the one above and choose whichever field I want to uncomment
//but in order to the model normal, only field is allowed to exist.
@*<input type="hidden" asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[x].CttvThuocBangId" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[x].CongThucDong" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[x].CauHinhBang_Cha" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[x].TenDong" />*@
}
```

My TenDongThuocCongTies Model as request:

```
public class TenDongThuocVeCongTyModel
{
    public int CttvThuocBangId { get; set; }
    public int CauHinhBangId { get; set; }
    public string CongThucDong { get; set; }
    public string TenDong { get; set; }
    public int CauHinhBang_Cha { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string inputValue { get; set; }
}
```

My Model:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("post-item")]
    public IActionResult PostHoaCheLuyen(TongHopItemHoaCheLuyenModel model)
    {
    }
```

Edit: The data passing back to Controller is not wrong. It just turn everything to null if I pass more than one field. It doesn't return any kind of error so I don't know how to fix it. I am hoping to see anyone who used to meet the same situation as me can solve it for me.

Comment: Can you post TenDongThuocCongTie pls?

Comment: I have updated it in the question.

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of TongHopItemHoaCheLuyenModel?

Comment: I'm trying to get a TongHopItemHoaCheLuyenModel in it contain a list of multiple others model.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code,and it can work.Maybe you need to check if your model properties' names and types are right.Or have you added other properties to the model which are not existed in `TongHopItemHoaCheLuyenModel`.

Models:

```
public class TongHopItemHoaCheLuyenModel { 
        public List<LayThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens> layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens { get; set; }
    }
    public class LayThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens {
        public List<TenDongThuocVeCongTyModel> TenDongThuocCongTies { get; set; }
        public int CttvId { get; set; }
        public int CttvThuocBangId { get; set; }
        public int CauHinhBangId { get; set; }
        public string TenDong { get; set; }
        public string CongThucDong { get; set; }
        public string DichCongThuc { get; set; }
        public int listId { get; set; }


    }
    public class TenDongThuocVeCongTyModel
    {
        public int CttvThuocBangId { get; set; }
        public int CauHinhBangId { get; set; }
        public string CongThucDong { get; set; }
        public string TenDong { get; set; }
        public int CauHinhBang_Cha { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string inputValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Actions:

```
public IActionResult TestBindList()
        {
            TongHopItemHoaCheLuyenModel t = new TongHopItemHoaCheLuyenModel()
            {
                layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens = new List<LayThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens> {
                    new LayThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens(){
                         CauHinhBangId=1,
                         CttvId=1,
                         CttvThuocBangId=1,
                         listId=1,
                         CongThucDong="ctd1",
                         DichCongThuc="dct1",
                         TenDong="td1",
                         TenDongThuocCongTies=new List<TenDongThuocVeCongTyModel>(){
                             new TenDongThuocVeCongTyModel(){
                                 CauHinhBangId=1,
                                 CttvThuocBangId=1,
                                 CauHinhBang_Cha=1,
                                 CongThucDong="ctd1",
                                 TenDong="td1",
                                 inputValue="value1"
                             },
                             new TenDongThuocVeCongTyModel(){
                                 CauHinhBangId=1,
                                 CttvThuocBangId=1,
                                 CauHinhBang_Cha=1,
                                 CongThucDong="ctd1",
                                 TenDong="td1",
                                 inputValue="value2"
                             }
                         }
                    },
                    new LayThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens(){
                         CauHinhBangId=2,
                         CttvId=2,
                         CttvThuocBangId=2,
                         listId=2,
                         CongThucDong="ctd2",
                         DichCongThuc="dct2",
                         TenDong="td2",
                         TenDongThuocCongTies=new List<TenDongThuocVeCongTyModel>(){
                             new TenDongThuocVeCongTyModel(){
                                 CauHinhBangId=2,
                                 CttvThuocBangId=2,
                                 CauHinhBang_Cha=2,
                                 CongThucDong="ctd2",
                                 TenDong="td2",
                                 inputValue="value01"
                             },
                             new TenDongThuocVeCongTyModel(){
                                 CauHinhBangId=2,
                                 CttvThuocBangId=2,
                                 CauHinhBang_Cha=2,
                                 CongThucDong="ctd2",
                                 TenDong="td2",
                                 inputValue="value02"
                             }
                         }
                    }
                }
            };
            return View(t);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PostHoaCheLuyen(TongHopItemHoaCheLuyenModel model)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

View:

```
@model xxx.xxx.TongHopItemHoaCheLuyenModel
<form method="post" asp-action="PostHoaCheLuyen">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens.Count; i++)
    {
        //Value for Model
        <input  asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].CttvId" />
        <input  asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].CttvThuocBangId" />
        <input  asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].CauHinhBangId" />
        <input  asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].TenDong" />
        <input  asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].CongThucDong" />
        <input  asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].DichCongThuc" />
        <input  asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].listId" />
        var dataTarget = "#collapse" + i.ToString();
        var tempid = "collapse" + i.ToString();
        var danhmuc = Model.layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens.ElementAt(i);
        for (int x = 0; x < danhmuc.TenDongThuocCongTies.Count; x++)
        {
            <input  asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[x].CauHinhBangId" />
            //If I un-comment even one of the line below, the model become null.
            //Each of them field is not special. I can comment the one above and choose whichever field I want to uncomment
            //but in order to the model normal, only field is allowed to exist.
            <input  asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[x].CttvThuocBangId" />
                <input  asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[x].CongThucDong" />
                <input  asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[x].CauHinhBang_Cha" />
                <input  asp-for="layThongTinBangThuocCongTyThanhViens[i].TenDongThuocCongTies[x].TenDong" />
        }
    }
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

result:
[image]